# Password randomiser: creates the same password

Tags: java, random

The point is to make a password randomiser, but my problem is that my code makes the same password all the time. I have tried all kind of stuff and this is the latest one where I have gotten by using the Internet.

Main class:

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());
    }
}
```

The `Program` class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class PasswordRandomizer {
    // Define the variables

    private Random password = new Random();
    private int length;
    private String character; 

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        //creates a new object, uses the given password length
        this.length = length;

        String characters = "";

            Random rndNumbers = new Random();
            int randomnumber = 0;


            for (int nbr = 1; nbr < length; nbr++) {
                randomnumber = rndNumbers.nextInt(25);

                char character = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(randomnumber);
                characters = characters + character; 
            }

        System.out.println(characters);
        this.character = characters;
    }


    public String createPassword() {
        // write code that returns a randomized password
        PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        //consists of symbols a-z and is of the length given as a parameter to the constructor
        return this.character;  
    }
}
```

In the `PasswordRandomizer` method, there is the line `System.out.println(characters);` which prints out the randomized password every time. BUT the different password doesn't come in the `createPassword` method, only the first one which results in the same password all the time in the output.

Comment: So your code doesn't work as expected? Welcome to Code Review anyway! However, I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: your `createPassword()` invokes a new instance and you lose whatever randomization it does. Just move some of your constructor code to this method.

Comment: If you want to create random numbers, you should Use SecureRandom instead of Random. Random is not random enough for security.

Comment: @asgs why would you call him dumb..? That's kinda messed up man. Maybe s/he's just new.

Comment: @LostBam I called that method dumb. I don't believe in insults, especially when it comes to programming. I've been there and done that.

Comment: @asgs Misinterpreted it, my mistake.

Comment: Do I see a String named character? Nice.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment, your method `createPassword()` invokes the constructor and creates a new set of instance variables which are lost. Moving your "randomization" code to this method fixes it. Check out the [sample at Ideone](http://ideone.com/elGbbH). The modified constructor and `createPassword()` code is below.

```
public PasswordRandomizer (int length) {
        //creates a new object, uses the given password length
        this.length = length;

}     

public String createPassword() {
        String characters = "";

        Random rndNumbers = new Random();
        int randomnumber = 0;
        for (int nbr = 1; nbr < length; nbr++) {
            randomnumber = rndNumbers.nextInt(25);
            char character = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(randomnumber);
            characters = characters + character; 
        }

        System.out.println(characters);
        return characters;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you create 2 instances of `Random` and 2 instances of `PasswordRandomizer`.

You keep calling `createPassword()` (on one of the instances) which creates a `PasswordRandomizer` object (and throws it away) and then just returns `this.character;` (not `randomizer.character` which would give you the behaviour you seek).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String createPassword() {
        // write code that returns a randomized password
        PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        //consists of symbols a-z and is of the length given as a parameter to the constructor
        return randomizer.character;  //This could be a simple fix.
    }
```